# Javascript way to create multiple HTML containers?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been following this tutorial: http://mariechatfield.com/tutorials/firebase/step5.html

But I wanted to spice it up and instead of printing the last database object, I want to print all of them.

I've tried printing off the database, which works fine. I just need to edit the Html. I tried using a line break, but nothing either. It keeps appending to the starting string instead of making a new line/container.

```
recommendations.limitToLast(10).on('child_added',     function(childSnapshot) {
  // Get the recommendation data from the most recent snapshot of data
  // added to the recommendations list in Firebase
 recommendation = childSnapshot.val();
  console.log(recommendation);

  // Update the HTML to display the recommendation text
  $("#title").append(recommendation.title)

  $("#presenter").append(recommendation.presenter)
  $("#link").append(recommendation.link)
  var x = '\n';
  x;

  // Make the link actually work and direct to the URL provided
  $("#link").attr("href", recommendation.link)
});
```

I hope to be able to have an individual container for each database element.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Comment: Thanks y'all! It's not exact yet but it's better. I put the <br> tag in like this: var mybr = document.createElement('br');
  $("#title").append(mybr);

Comment: @RandyCasburn Sounds like an answer to me. :)

Comment: @RandyCasburn Do post your solution as an answer so the OP can mark it as the correct answer mate. Cheers.

Comment: @AndrewL64 - done.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - posted comment as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Per request, posting comment as answer:

Great job! The only change you have to make is to change `\n` to `<br>`. HTML removes whitespace (like your newline). So to replicate that line break you have to use the HTML BR element. Then you'll need to append that to your existing HTML of-course.